# Duplicated record in Sitecore SOLR index

Tags: solr, sitecore

In CM, I have an item (called it ItemA) version 1. When a content editor edit ItemA, the version increment by 1. So now the version is 2.
Then the content editor publish ItemA through workflow. Now the web database is updated with ItemA version 2.
By right, when the web database only has the latest version of the item, the index also will be updated to contains only that particular version of item

Currently, I have a custom crawler for separate SOLR index core. And the custom index always get append with new version.
When I search for ItemA in this custom SOLR index, it returns me 2 records where both records are referring to the same item but with different version.

```
<doc><str name="_uniqueid">sitecore://web/{1830d10d-bb75-48ee-91f6-5fec6dfabea9}?lang=en&ver=1</str></doc>

<doc><str name="_uniqueid">sitecore://web/{1830d10d-bb75-48ee-91f6-5fec6dfabea9}?lang=en&ver=2</str></doc>
```

I would like the indexing to be updated or controlled by CM only, so I have defined the following strategy:

- Core - /sync
- Master - /sync
- Web - /manual
- CustomIndex - /manual

For custom index, I have a custom crawler associated with it. This custom crawler will add new entry whenever I publish a new version of item.

So, I would like to know how can I ensure that my custom SOLR index always get the copied of item being published to web.

Comment: Can you add your CustomIndex configurations here?

Comment: Is your custom index attached to the web database? Start by adding the config as Ahmed asked..

Comment: What is your Sitecore version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like you are experiencing a bug with old versions not being removed from the Solr Index. I had a similar issue here:

[Sitecore Solr remove versions from index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20124996/sitecore-solr-remove-versions-from-index)

If you are using the OnPublishEndAsync strategy then try this support fix provided by Sitecore.

https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/992608